# How do I get my R Shiny app to stop getting an invalid type (list) for a variable?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Here's the bit of code that I am most concerned with.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df1 <- reactive({read.csv("input.csv")})
  targets <- reactive({select(df1(), Lease.Sales, Retail.Sales, Net.Margin.Lease, Net.Margin.Retail)})
  drops <- reactive({c("Lease.Sales", "Retail.Sales", "Net.Margin.Lease", "Net.Margin.Retail")})
  df2 <- reactive({df1()[, !(names(df1()) %in% drops())]})
  
  df <- reactive({lapply(df2(), function(x) {
    x <- as.numeric(gsub('[$,]', '', x))
  })})
  
  #x <- reactive({as.matrix(df())})
  #y <- reactive({as.matrix(targets()[1])})
  
  #multivar_reg <- t(cov(y(), x()) %*% solve(cov(x())))
  
  leaseType <- reactive({lm(as.matrix(targets()[1]) ~ as.matrix(df()))$coeff})
  retailType <- reactive({lm(as.matrix(targets()[2]) ~ as.matrix(df()))$coeff})
  leaseMargin <- reactive({lm(as.matrix(targets()[3]) ~ as.matrix(df()))$coeff})
  retailMargin <- reactive({lm(as.matrix(targets()[4]) ~ as.matrix(df()))$coeff})
```

When it gets to any `lm` part, in this case any of the lease/retail types/margin, it says the following. `invalid type (list) for variable 'as.matrix(df())'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: (1) `lapply` is returning a list, not a frame. You can work around this with `as.data.frame(lapply(...))` if you must. (2) Perhaps this is a simplified example (thanks, if it is), but your use of `reactive` in most of these cases is completely unnecessary: if `df1` never changes, for instance, just define it as `df1 <- read.csv(...)` and use it as a regular (non-reactive) variable.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. If you want to basically just copy and paste your comment as an answer I will give it the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `lapply(...)` is returning a `list`, not a `data.frame`. While there is a form of `as.matrix` that knows what to do with a `data.frame`, there is not one that knows what to do with a `list`. (A `data.frame` is effectively a `list` where all its elements are the same length. With this in mind, it is "obviously" rectangular in a sense, so it translates rather directly and unambiguously to a matrix. Unfortunately, a `list` is not necessarily rectangular, so there is no sane way to make assumptions of converting to a matrix ... so they don't try.)

  You can work around this with `as.data.frame(lapply(...))`.
- In case this is not a simplified example (if it is, thank you), then most of your use of `reactive` is unnecessary, just use `df1 <- read.csv(...)` and deal with it as a "normal" variable.

  If instead the CSV file may change periodically, then you likely want something like

  ```r
  df1 <- shiny::reactiveFileReader(3000, session, "input.csv", read.csv)
  ```

  which will check every 3000 milliseconds for an update to the file (i.e., its modification time). If a change is detected, then it uses `read.csv` here to read the file; if you have special reading needs, you'll need to update this,  perhaps with an anonymous function for special arguments.

  Since this version is still reactive, you'll still use `df1()` elsewhere.